# Controlling verbosity of byte-compilation (CL library)

Tags: emacs, compilation, elisp

When byte-compiling several eLisp files in a batch the output from the compiler is cluttered with `` Warning: function `position' from cl package called at runtime `` warnings. I understand, although don't agree that much with the policy on `cl` package. But this makes spotting other, more useful warnings more difficult. So, while there's no real way to avoid the warning, is there a way to selectively shut off all warnings of a certain pattern?

EDIT: (attached an example)

*create file called doodles.el*

```
(require 'cl)
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))

(dotimes (i 1)
  (position ?\x "x"))
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-compile-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> `doodles.el`

Switch to `*Compile-Log*` buffer:

```
doodles.el:1:1:Warning: cl package required at runtime
```

this is what you get.

Comment: You have two conflicting uses of `(require 'cl)` above (one plain and one wrapped in `eval-when-compile`); either use one or the other, but not both.  You also mention two different warnings (one in the text and a different one in your example).  Please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control byte-compiler warnings with a Local variables block that sets the `byte-compile-warnings` variable. To turn off the CL-at-runtime warning, place this near the end of your module:

```
;; Local Variables:
;; byte-compile-warnings: (not cl-functions)
;; End:
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning `function position from cl package called at runtime` is not there because of the policy on CL (well, it does have something to do with it, admittedly) but is pointing out an actual real problem: you use `position` in a file which does not `(require 'cl)`.  The file probably does `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))` which means CL is available during compilation (a.g. to expand CL macros), but will not be loaded at run time.

Often this does not result in a bug, because some other file somewhere does `(require 'cl)` for you, but that's just you being lucky.

Comment: @wvxvw: I didn't tell you to add `(require 'cl)` but to remove the `eval-when-compile` wrapper.

Comment: The "cl package required at runtime" warning does not imply that your code has something that looks sufficiently suspicious that it could be a bug (contrary to the other warning), but it's only there to remind you that the CL package is discouraged because it uses the namespace in an unclean way.  In the next Emacs release, there will be a `cl-lib` package, which is like `cl` but is clean (all the functions/macros it defines start with the `cl-` prefix), such that it does not come with a warning.